# Seeking segmentation methods for this light microscope image

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, color

Although I am not new to math or programming, I am a total newbie to image segmentation.  I have the following light microscope image

[image: H&E Stail]
and I would like to segment it into cytoplasm (the magenta background) vs. the nuclei (the round-ish objects that look like cells).  I am working in MATLAB.

I was hoping someone with segmentation or image processing experience could tell me what they thought would be an efficient approach.

First, do you see any issues with this image that I ought to pre-process out?  E.g. non-uniform background illumination, noise, etc.  I am not familiar with how to identify these things visually in an image.

Secondly, there are two dominant colors in this image, corresponding to two dyes (hematoxylin and eosin, or "H&E" for short).  The cytoplasm and nuclei have different colors, which in principle we know the RGB values of.  So I first tried a method of color deconvolution by Ruifrok to try to separate out the pink from the purple.

Once I did that, the cytoplasm and nuclei seem to have very different textures.  I tried a range filter and got the result below:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions for where I can go from here?  How can I eliminate the regions with cytoplasm and end up with clearly segmented nuclei?

I do not know much about graph cuts.  Do you think they would be useful?

Please let me know if I need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

People were approaching similar problems with methods deriving from [Watersheds thresholding](http://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/the-watershed-transform-strategies-for-image-segmentation.html?refresh=true). [Here](http://fiji.sc/Nuclei_Watershed_Separation), is a sample of Nuclei Seperation, and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html#gsc.tab=0) is an OpenCV sample. You might try it out.

Comment: Thanks!  This is useful to know.  I hadn't thought of using watershed-based methods here, because the nuclei are clear and contain nucleoli, so they aren't local extrema...maybe it's worth a quick try.

Comment: It would be good if you share the results here so that people get an idea.

Comment: Will do so...unfortunately have been a little busy right now with other things. :)  I may try some kind of snakes type method first.

Answer (score 0):

There an algorithm in [CellProfiler](http://cellprofiler.org). It's basic, but it may help you if you are a beginner. The algorithm separates the channels, applies a threshold to detect roughly the nuclei, then use the result to feed a watershed constrained.

Comment: Thank you...this might be the color deconvolution algorithm by Ruifrok.  This is a good suggestion.

Comment: This algorithm might be used as a first step, but the end is thresholding+watershed.

Comment: Sorry I indeed just meant the first step