# Detect circles in image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, hough-transform

I have an image that has pixelated circles in it (a cross section of wires). I want to identify the wires, their location and count them.

The circles never overlap and the wires are all within a 95% radius. However the spacing might not be exact as there can be gaps between the wires.

What is a good way to find the geometric mean of the group of pixels that represent a wire?

[image]
The above picture is what I would like to do, to fit a circle to a group of pixels (which I did using paint). I would think that the first step is to find the geometric mean of the group.

I did try using a tophat kernel and threshold to emphasize the centers, but I end up with a few pixels and no center pixel. I need to identify the center and end up with only one pixel which is difficult to do with thresholding since the pixel values differ in brightness. 
[image]

Raw picture:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a raw picture?

Comment: Yep, its small though

Comment: This is too low res. Why do you work with such an image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Normalize your image to range $[0,255]$.

2) Select a threshold and threshold the image. For your image, what worked is: $\tau=[140-150]$.

3) Compute a Euclidean [distance transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform).

4) Apply [watersheds segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)).

If I apply this procedure, here is what I get:
[image]

Not perfect, but maybe a good start. The result looks similar to performing a Voronoi diagram on a smoothed/noise filtered version of the image.

Now to each region, one could fit a circle, using any algorithm (edge extraction and fitting or Hough transform etc.) For now, I used a simple circle fitting to the edges:

[image]

Again, not the best, but could be a sufficient starting point.

I also think that you would find the following useful:

> [Segmentation Methods for Light Microscope Image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29022/seeking-segmentation-methods-for-this-light-microscope-image/29023#29023)
>
> [Detecting Spheric Particles](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30016/how-to-calculate-particles-sizes-for-spheric-particles-with-overlapping-and-supe)